# Passing key to URL request Swift

Tags: json, swift, http, url, request

I need to fetch data from a web endpoint. I will include the instructions below. I am passing the the X-ACCESS-KEY incorrectly because I get the error that the key is invalid or the bin doesn't belong to my account when I run the code. How do I correctly pass the key to the request then decode the response?

*we've hosted a JSON file at at this url: https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/646bed328e4aa6225ea22a79. Your job is to write a script to
download the contents of the URL (hint: The X-ACCESS-KEY is $2b$10$Ke1iwieFO7/7qsSKU.GYU.oYXZMW1EeHrwd4xx9ylboJik5mstZk6)
sort the data by each elements 'bar' key
filter out elements where 'baz' is not divisible by 3
concatenate each elements 'foo' value*

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/646bed328e4aa6225ea22a79")!
let key = "$2b$10$Ke1iwieFO7/7qsSKU.GYU.oYXZMW1EeHrwd4xx9ylboJik5mstZk6)"
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("Bearer \(key)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Master-Key")

var jsonData: Data?
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, err) in
    if let error = err {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    } else if let data = data {
        jsonData = data
        processData()
    }
}

task.resume()

func processData(){
    if let jsonData = jsonData,
       let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any], let records = jsonObject["records"] as? [[String: Any]] {
      
    }
}
```

Comment: The token looks so suspicious, are you sure it's not only the last component of that key string?

Comment: Remove “Bearer” from the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues:

1. Joakim correctly stated that you have to specify just the key without leading `Bearer` .
2. And the hint clearly says it's `X-Access-Key` not `X-Master-Key`

   ```
   request.addValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Access-Key")
   ```
3. The closing parenthesis at the end is not part of the token.